# How to memory map a file in Common Lisp on Linux?

Tags: linux, common-lisp

How can I achieve memory mapping in Common Lisp either through `cffi` or a custom library?

There is `void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);` in C language.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451190/how-do-i-memory-map-tmpfs-files-in-sbcl SBCL has a `mmap` in `sb-posix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already [How do I memory map tmpfs files in sbcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451190/how-do-i-memory-map-tmpfs-files-in-sbcl), but nowadays there is a portable library for that: just `(ql:quickload "mmap")`.

The repository is [here](https://github.com/Shinmera/mmap).

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations let you specify in a call to function `open` take the file should be memory-mapped. At least Allegro CL supports [`(open .. :mapped t)`](https://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/classes/excl/mapped-file-simple-stream.htm). This also works in macro `with-open-file` which expands into `open`.